# is a concrete slab walkout basement above, below, or on grade? For material use purposes not square footage

Tags: concrete, basement, flooring, adhesive, vinyl-flooring

I have a walkout basement with 1 long side and 1 shortside above grade... For material usage is this considered above/on grade? since the slab is not really below grade?

I need something like: https://www.homedepot.ca/product/roberts-7300-universal-vinyl-flooring-adhesive/1000851709 which says for concreate above/on but not below.

This is in Ontario, Canada.

Comment: Seems like any concern would be it soaking with water on top(flood in a basement for a time).  Could be mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slab above grade - an elevated concrete slab not in contact with the ground.

Slab on-grade - a concrete slab cast directly on the ground, that will be influenced by the moisture/water content in the soil, and could become damp, if a vapor barrier is not used.

Your basement is partially below grade (2 sides), but the slab is likely placed on the ground (slab-on-grade, SOG) unless there is a crawl space below.